# Quel article après le construction « [suj.] + (ne?) + [v.b.] + que » ?

Tags: grammaire, expressions-idiomatiques, négation, formulation-idiomatique

J'ai entendu cette construction plusieurs fois dans le discours quotidien, mais je n'arrive pas à trouver la règle exacte. Par exemple, je crois que je peux dire :

- Je veux que **du** saumon pour le dîner ce soir
- Comme travail aujourd'hui, j'ai que **deux** trucs à faire
- Non, j'ai besoin de qu'**une** pomme

Mais par contre, j'ai l'impression que je pourrais également dire :

- Je veux que **ça** pour le dîner ce soir
- Comme travail aujourd'hui, j'ai que **celui-ci et celui-là** à faire
- Non, j'ai besoin de **que** ça

Du coup, je me demande exactement quelle est la règle ici ? Peut-être que c'est idiomatique ? Ou peut-être ai-je mal entendu et mes exemples ne sont pas même bons.

Comment: [ceci u cela à faire].

Comment: @Lambie Même si je fais référence à deux choses en particulier ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. > Je veux que du saumon...

   Courant, à l'écrit ou soutenu : *Je ne veux que du saumon...*
2. > ...j'ai que deux trucs à faire.

   Courant, (*je n'ai que...*)
3. > ...j'ai besoin de qu'une pomme

   Incorrect. On dit/écrit:

   > J'ai besoin que d'une pomme / Je n'ai besoin que d'une pomme.
4. > Je veux que ça pour le dîner ce soir.

   Courant (je ne veux que ça...)
5. > ...j'ai que celui-ci et celui-là à faire

   Courant (je n'ai que...)
6. > ...j'ai besoin de que ça

   Relâché (j'ai besoin d'que ça), on entend plutôt:

   > J'ai besoin que d'ça (je n'ai besoin que de ça)

---

Après « [suj.] + (**ne**?) + [vb] + **que** », on peut trouver beaucoup de choses :

un article défini : *Je ne veux que la victoire.*
un article partitif : *Je ne veux que de la soupe.*
un adjectif possessif : *Je ne veux que ton crayon.*
un adjectif numéral: *Je ne veux que dix euros.*
un pronom personnel : *Je ne veux que vous dans mon équipe.*
un pronom démonstratif : *Je ne veux que celle-là.*
un pronom possessif : *Je ne veux que le tien.*
un pronom interrogatif : *Je ne veux que quoi ?*
une locution adverbiale : *Je ne veux qu'un peu de pluie.*
un infinitif : *Je ne veux que dormir.*
un adverbe : *Je ne veux que bien faire.*
un nom propre : *Je ne veux que Pierre.*
une préposition : *Je ne pars que dans une mois.*
...

En revanche, peu de chance de trouver une autre conjonction.

Comment: Merci beaucoup de m'avoir corrigé, mais je suis encore curieux s'il y a une règle ou pas que je peux essayer de me souvenir, ou si c'est vraiment juste « que + article indéfini + nom » et « que + ça » ?

Answer (score 1):

Il n'y a pas de règle quant à la sorte d'article que l'on doive utiliser ; ce qui dicte la sorte d'article c'est ce que vous avez à dire, ce que vous *voulez* dire, ce que le contexte indique qu'il faut dire. D'ailleurs dans vos constructions vous utilisez des articles (partitif, *du*, indéfini pluriel, *des*), mais aussi un adjectif (*deux*) et  des pronoms (*ça*,  *celui-ci*, *celui-là*). Vous pouvez aussi bien utiliser toutes sortes de mots (voir les nombreux exemples de mots dans cette [réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/43097/17649)), en particulier l'article défini ; il suffit pour cela que le contexte corresponde.

Par exemple, si on vous annonce qu'au repas il y aura à manger du saumon et aussi du thon, vous pouvez répondre ceci.

- Je ne veux que **le** saumon. (*Cela signifie que vous ne voulez pas **le** thon, c'est à dire en considérant le choix  sur le plan de ce qui est offert, mais cela pourrait aussi dire que vous ne voulez pas **de** thon ; cette dernière forme exprime le fait que ce n'est pas nécessairement ce thon qui à été préparé qui ne vous convient pas mais le thon en général ; donc, au lieu de la présente phrase vous pouvez utiliser la suivante.*)
- je ne veux que **du** saumon.

Donnée la possibilité, par exemple, que la commande que vous venez de passer au restaurant se trouve trop importante parce que certains de vos invités doivent s'absenter, pour modifier votre commande de poisson qui consiste de plusieurs plats de truites (tous les mêmes), vous pouvez dire ceci.

- Nous ne prendrons qu'**un** plat de truites.
  *ou*
- Nous ne prendrons qu'**un des** plats de truites que nous avions commandés. (*pronom « un », préposition « de » et article défini « les » contractés en « des » ; ce qui compte ici c'est le pronom « un », qui est l'élément central du syntagme nominal « un des plats de truites ».*)

Si, par exemple, cette commande de poisson consistait de deux plats de poisson, l'un de truites et l'autre un plat de brochet, vous avez  la possibilité de décommander en disant ceci.

- Nous ne prendrons que **le** plat de truites.
  *ou, s'il est clair que le plat de truites est le plat de poisson commandé en premier*
- Nous ne prendrons que **le** premier plat de poisson.
  *ou encore*
- Nous ne prendrons q'**un** plat de poisson, le plat de truites. (*Soit dit en passant, le statut grammatical de « un » est ambigu, soit c'est l'adjectif numéral « un », soit c'est l'article indéfini « un »*)

Il est clair que dans cet exemple le choix entre « le » et « un » n'est qu'une question de ce que vous voulez dire, qu'une question de votre choix de la façon de considérer la situation : « le » est utilisé parce que dans le background qui vous lie au restaurateur il existe le savoir commun d'une commande de plat de truite, « un » est utilisé dans la dernière phrase parce que dans ce savoir commun les deux plats sont du poisson et donc « plat de poisson » n'est pas différentiateur et tant que l'on ne sait pas duquel on parle (il est spécifié  après la virgule) il faut référer à ce plat comme étant indéterminé.

En ce qui concerne votre choix entre « Je veux que du saumon pour le dîner ce soir. » **(A)** et « Je veux que ça pour le dîner ce soir. » **(B)** tout est encore une fois une question de contexte.

Vous venez de dire **(A)**, à votre épouse par exemple, et vous continuez à parler ensemble de la raison pour ne vouloir que du saumon ; elle pourra vous demander si vous êtes sûr de votre choix ; elle peut le faire de deux façon ; d'abord, en posant la question « Est-tu sûr que *tu ne veux que* **du** saumon ? », mais alors elle répète « saumon », ce qui n'est pas du tout une faute (c'est un choix possible) ; ensuite elle pourra le faire de la façon suivante, en posant la question « Est-tu sûr que *tu ne veux que* **ça** ? » ; dans ce cas, puisque l'on sait de quoi il s'agit (du saumon) on peut utiliser à la place de « saumon » le pronom « ça ». Si vous voulez maintenant confirmer que c'est bien ce que vous voulez vous avez les mêmes possibilités et vous pouvez dire soit « Oui, je ne veux que du saumon. » ou bien « Oui, je ne veux que **ça**. ».

La seule règle en rapport avec le choix à faire est la règle fondamentale qui régit l'emploi des pronom et des articles définis : il doit exister quelque part (dans la phrase même ou dans une autre phrase ou dans le contexte) un référent pour ces mots-là, soit avant (plupart des cas), soit après.